# Проблема: Retrofit2 GsonConverterFactory создает объект с пустыми полями

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста:
Для получения данных из веб сервиса через JSOM использую клиент Retrofit 2. (из build.gradle:)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

При вызове метода GET должен возвращаться лист объектов Article, ниже объявление метода в интерфейсе IWebServiceAPI.java

```
@GET("dev/mobile/get.php")
Call<List<Article>> listArticles(@Query("timesta`mp") String timestamp);`
```

Объект Article объявлен как:
   public class Article {

```
private String mType;
private long mDateLong;
private long mTimestamp;
private String mID;
private String mTitle;
private String mContent;
private String mDrawing;
private String mTags;
```

При тестировании создаю объект retrofit

```
private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(IWebServiceAPI.base_WebAPI_URL)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .build();
```

Далее создаю сервис так как это описано в [manual](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
     // Retrofit создает WebService (реализацию IWebServiceAPI interface).
     IWebServiceAPI webService = retrofit.create(IWebServiceAPI.class);

```
 // Send the GET request to the web service using Retrofit to add the article.
 Call<List<Article>> call = webService.listArticles("1441886076");

 Response<List<Article>> response = call.execute();

 // Получаю объект Response, смотрю на его состав
 Log.d(TAG, "response created. HTTP status code=" + response.code() + "; isSuccess=" + response.isSuccess() + "; message=" + response.message() + "Response.body()=" + response.body());
```

В логах появляется запись что запрос к серверу выполнен успешно:

```
Response.raw()=Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url
```

Ожидаю увидеть в `response.body()` нужный мне массив `List<Article> articles = response.body();`

Но! При выводе в лог, вижу что вижу что retrofit скачал и распарсил 16 записей вида, но вот все поля что он распарсил пустые. См. ниже лог из LogCat:

```
Article{mType='null', mDateLong='0', mtimestamp='0', mID='null', mTitle='null', mContent='null', mDrawing='null', mTags='null'}
```

Вопрос - почему объект не был распарсен правильно и что и где нужно указать чтобы GsonConverterFactory правильно парсил данные?

Вот пример того что возвращает веб сервис если запустить его в "ручном" режиме (если вызывать веб сервис из строки браузера):

```
[
   {
      "Type": "type_schedule",
      "DateLong": "",
      "timestamp": 1443005110,
      "ID": "494",
      "Title": "\u0411\u0438\u0437\u043d\u0435\u0441-\u043b\u0430\u0433\u0435\u0440\u044c &quot;\u0421\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u0430 \u0438 \u0442\u0435\u0445\u043d\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u044f \u0443\u043f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043b\u044e\u0434\u044c\u043c\u0438 \u0432 \u0431\u0438\u0437\u043d\u0435\u0441\u0435&quot;",
      "Content": "http:\/\/www.mrybakov.ru\/order\/hr\/bcamp_hr\/?content=Y",
      "Drawing": "",
      "Tags": ""
   },... ]
```

Comment: А как Gson должен ассоциировать поля модели `Article` с JSON? Вы либо в модели анотируйте поля либо давайте им имена в соответствии с именами в JSON. То есть не `mType` a `Type`

Comment: Точно, спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 1):

Похоже проблема была в объявлении класса `Article`. Класс `Article` пересоздал c помощью сервиса http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, после чего у полей появилось объявление:

```
@SerializedName("Type")   
@Expose    
private String mType;
```

а также конструктор, инициирующий все поля:

```
public Article(String Type, String DateLong, long timestamp, String ID, String Title, String Content, String Drawing, String Tags) {    
    this.mType = Type;        
    this.mDateLong = DateLong;    
    this.mTimestamp = timestamp;    
    this.mID = ID;    
    this.mTitle = Title;    
    this.mContent = Content;    
    this.mDrawing = Drawing;    
    this.mTags = Tags;    
}
```

и тогда `response` объект стал возвращать данные из веб сервиса:

```
Article{Type='type_article', DateLong=1446850800, timestamp=1447057275, ID='library_ca_ca_347', Title='Выпуск 347'....}
```